# Cutoff Text in Trade screen

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'd like to sell all my unclaimed clothing, particularly all the Giant Cave Spider Silk... but I don't want to sell ropes.  Unfortunately I can only see "Giant Cave Spider S" in the trade menu.

When I've had this cutoff text problem in other menus, hitting tab a few times allowed me to see it.  That doesn't work in the trade menu.

I have zoomed out, making the text small and maximized the window, but no help since it seems that menu is only a fixed width.  Only way I can identify an item is to V each item one at a time.

Any suggestions on how to workaround/resolve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the cursor is over the good, hit `v` to view the specific good.

Alternately, designate a nice large stockpile near your trade depot that accepts only the kinds of stuff you want to offer for trade to make your life - and your trading times - easier.

Comment: Your second suggestion is excellent.  When I do "Move goods to stockpile" then I will be able to see based on the distance which ones are in the nearby stockpile.  Additionally things I don't want to sell like ropes won't be in the same Finished Goods Bin as things I do want to sell.  As mentioned "Only way I can identify an item is to V each item one at a time." which involves 3 times as many keystrokes.